# Excel-like behaviour of Grids in Ext JS

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I'm trying to figure out a way to have an Excel-like behavior with the Grids on Ext JS.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a3c17031e5cfb14481c9661d961f1947) is the sample grid I am working with. So far we can already naviguate through the cells with the arrows but only in edit mode.

However what I am trying to reach is the naviguation with the arrows, TAB and Enter keys outside of the edit mode, just like excel.

I tried to integrate this [piece of code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9c0c0c94c9dfa003536b1007ad8bd36a) which overrides the Editor class, hoping that it would change the behavior of the cells but it doesn't change a thing.

I believe this is the most important part that overrides the Editor class and tries to include the keys input :

```
Ext.override(Ext.Editor, {
startEdit: function (el, value) {
    var me = this,
        field = me.field;

    me.completeEdit();
    me.boundEl = Ext.get(el);
    value = Ext.isDefined(value) ? value : me.boundEl.dom.innerHTML;

    if (!me.rendered) {
        me.render(me.parentEl || document.body);
    }

    if (me.fireEvent('beforestartedit', me, me.boundEl, value) !== false) {
        me.startValue = value;
        me.show();
        field.reset();

        if (deleteGridCellValue) {
            field.setValue('');
            me.editing = true;
            me.completeEdit();
            deleteGridCellValue = false; // reset global variable
        }
        else {
            if (newGridCellValue == '') {
                // default behaviour of Ext.Editor (see source if needed)
                field.setValue(value);
            }
            else {
                // custom behaviour to handle an alphanumeric key press from non-edit mode
                field.setRawValue(newGridCellValue);
                newGridCellValue = ''; // reset global variable

                if (field instanceof Ext.form.field.ComboBox) {
                    // force the combo box's filtered dropdown list to be displayed (some browsers need this)
                    field.doQueryTask.delay(field.queryDelay);
                }
            }

            me.realign(true);
            field.focus(false, 10);
            if (field.autoSize) {
                field.autoSize();
            }
            me.editing = true;
        }
    }
}
});
```

This is the first time that I am working on a project that is outside of Comp-Sci classes so any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: You can use the [`spreadsheet`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.grid.selection.SpreadsheetModel.html) selection model.

Comment: Thank you ! That's one thing taken care of, but can I easily implement it with the Grids ?

Comment: Well, you would need to code like 4 lines.